# error scanning from adf with scanimage - setting of option --source failed (Invalid argument)

Tags: scanning

I have tried to scan from ADF with scan image. Canon MF237. I am getting this error:

```
scanimage --source ADF --format tiff --batch=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_p%04d.tiff  --resolution 150

scanimage: setting of option --source failed (Invalid argument)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several ways until I have executed scanimage --help.

It gave me regular help, but then halted for few seconds and then gave additional commands for my specific printer.

```
Scan mode:
    --resolution auto||75|150|300|600dpi [75]
        Sets the resolution of the scanned image.
    --mode auto|Color|Gray|Lineart [Color]
        Selects the scan mode (e.g., lineart, monochrome, or color).
    --source Flatbed|Automatic Document Feeder [Flatbed]
        Selects the scan source (such as a document-feeder). Set source before
        mode and resolution. Resets mode and resolution to auto values.
    --button-controlled[=(yes|no)] [no]
        When enabled, scan process will not start immediately. To proceed,
        press "SCAN" button (for MP150) or "COLOR" button (for other models).
        To cancel, press "GRAY" button.
```

On first sight it did not seems to help, but then I have tried the option in a full name within quotation marks:

```
scanimage --source "Automatic Document Feeder" --format tiff --batch=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_p%04d.tiff  --resolution 150
```

It worked.